# Vue 2.x vee-validate v3 Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vee-validate

Getting:  Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a is not a constructor
at runtime running the app with vee-validate.

Most issues related to this seem to be with Vue3 as vee-validate V3 is not compattible but i can't find anything with Vue2 and vee-validate v3

npm run does not throw any errors

Using Vue 2 and vee-validate@3.4.3 and Vue@2.6.14

main.js

```
import validation from './validation'
Vue.use(validation)
```

validation.js

```
import { ValidationProvider, extend, setInteractionMode } from 'vee-validate'
import { required, email } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'




 function RegisterExtensions () {
  extend('required', {
    ...required,
    message: 'Dit veld is verplicht'
  })

  extend('email', {
    ...email,
    message: 'Dit is geen geldig E-mailadres'
  })
}

 const install = function (Vue) {
  RegisterExtensions()

  Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider)
  setInteractionMode('eager')
}

export default { install }
```

Runtime throws:

```
vee-validate.esm.js:861 Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a is not a constructor
    at eval (vee-validate.esm.js:861:17)
    at Module../node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.esm.js (plinqPackageComposer.umd.js:2834:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (plinqPackageComposer.umd.js:30:30)
    at eval (3-enter-details.vue?./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options:14:70)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/steps/3-enter-details.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (plinqPackageComposer.umd.js:478:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (plinqPackageComposer.umd.js:30:30)
    at eval (VM10196 3-enter-details.vue:2:291)
    at Module../src/steps/3-enter-details.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (plinqPackageComposer.umd.js:3980:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (plinqPackageComposer.umd.js:30:30)
    at eval (VM10196 3-enter-details.vue:3:103)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Vue2? Vue3 was [recently made the default](https://twitter.com/vuejs/status/1490592213184573441)

Comment: My package.json has "vue": "^2.6.14", in dependencies so it should be Vue2? If not, how do i force it to be Vue2?

Comment: Solved! The problem was that I was building the app with vue-cli-service build, the demo.html this generates has a script scr to https://unpkg.com/vue which defaults to Vue 3. So it broke because it was Vue3.